# Updating sub document map in n1q1 query CB

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Here is my document in CB,

```
{
    "users": {
        "11111": "ACTIVE",
        "22222": "ACTIVE",
        "33333": "ACTIVE",
        "44444": "ACTIVE",
        "55555": "ACTIVE",
        "666666": "ACTIVE",
        "777777": "ACTIVE",
        "888888": "ACTIVE"
    }
}
```

I want to update all keys of this users map to 0 instead of active.

output expected

```
{
    "users": {
        "11111": 0,
        "22222": 0,
        "33333": 0,
        "44444": 0,
        "55555": 0,
        "666666": 0,
        "777777": 0,
        "888888": 0
    }
}
```

I tried this

> UPDATE bucketname SET x=0 FOR x in bucketname.users END WHERE
> meta().id='%documentKey%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE mybucket AS b
SET b.users = OBJECT n:0 FOR n:v IN b.users END
WHERE ......
```

Construct new object and and set the value

```
FOR n:v IN b.users END
   iterates each field of b.users (n holds name, v holds value)

OBJECT n:0  
   Construct new object field name from n and value is 0 constant
```